# Display Search result in a table

Tags: php, laravel

So i create a search engine in my laravel application, the only problem i have is displaying it on the same page,

this is what i have in my views

```
<div class="search">
        {{Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/search', 'method' => 'post'))}}
            {{Form::text('keyword',null,array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter keyword...'
            ))}}<br>
            {{Form::submit()}}

    </div>
<br>
    <div class="searchs">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Date Created</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </thead>
                <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

and in my controller

```
public function search_keyword()
{
    $input = Input::get('keyword');
    $result = Post::where('title','LIKE','%' .$input. '%')->get();
    return Redirect::route('index')
        ->with('result',$result);
}
```

but i was hoping that i could do this in ajax request but I don't know jquery or even js.. help

Comment: Programming requires that you actually have knowledge of the progamming language you are using. If you don't know JavaScript, I suggest you learn at least some basics and try to solve the problem yourself, before asking for a solution.

Comment: uhm sorry i really dont know the basics of js, but anyway, i just want to display the result of my query to the same page where i made the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to catch the submit of the form with Javascript (vanilla or e.g. jquery), find the value the user is searching for and start an ajax request. (jQuery $.get() or native XMLHttpRequest())
2. Now you need to make sure that laravel accepts the ajax request properly and return the request as JSON.
3. If your request successfully returns data, use the success function of the ajax request to process the data. During the search, you could show some loading icon to notify the user that the search process is running.

To start with, add an id to the form and use jquery to listen for the submit event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#my-form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
                url: "/api/search",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    value: $("input:first").val()
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Next, register a route for the `/api/search` request and return your search request with `return response()->json(['result' => $result]);` (laravel 5)

If everything is right, you should see the result in the console of your browser.